# How can i extract dates from the column which are in different format?

Tags: python, powerquery

[image]

I tried using the datefinder library by first converting the column into a string.
I tried extracting the numbers from the column, but I could not extract all the numbers or all the dates.

is there any library that will automatically extract the date? or what are the possible ways to extract the dates which are in a different format?

Comment: I don't understand your question: People posting bad screenshots typically don't care about date formats.

Comment: To be honest, it looks like this is not possible. Let's take the `2022-07-05` example. It is not clear if this is in `%Y-%m-%d` or in `%Y-%d-%m`. In principal, both are valid options and no library could decide which is correct. Maybe a library could parse which is more likly, but this can cause big problems.

Comment: You can use custom format strings to import dates from text using the specific format strings, like  `= DateTime.FromText( "2000-02-08T03:45:12Z", [ Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"] )`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't "pretty" but it seems to get the job done using what you show in your screen clip.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Related Content", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Related Content", "Related Content - Copy"),
    #"Uppercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Related Content - Copy", Text.Upper, type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text","DECEMBER","12",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","NOVEMBER","11",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","OCTOBER","10",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","SEPTEMBER","9",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value4" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value3","AUGUST","08",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value5" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value4","JULY","07",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value6" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value5","JUNE","06",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value7" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value6","MAY","05",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value8" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value7","APRIL","04",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value9" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value8","MARCH","03",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value10" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value9","FEBRUARY","02",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value11" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value10","JANUARY","01",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value12" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value11","DEC","12",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value13" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value12","NOV","11",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value14" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value13","OCT","10",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value15" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value14","SEP","09",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value16" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value15","AUG","08",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value17" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value16","JUL","07",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value18" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value17","JUN","06",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value19" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value18","MAY","05",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value20" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value19","APR","04",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value21" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value20","MAR","03",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value22" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value21","FEB","02",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value23" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value22","JAN","01",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value24" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value23","03KET","MARKET",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value25" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value24","V2","V-TWO",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Related Content - Copy"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value25", "Custom", each Text.Select([#"Related Content - Copy"],{"0".."9"})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if Text.Length([Custom])=5 then "0" & [Custom] else [Custom]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2", each try Date.FromText([Custom.1]) otherwise #date(Number.From(Text.Middle([Custom.1],4,Text.Length([Custom.1])-4)), Number.From(Text.Middle([Custom.1],2,2)), Number.From(Text.Start([Custom.1],2)))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Related Content", "Custom.2"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

I used more add column steps for this than I would probably use for myself, but I figured it might help you follow along with what I was doing with the data.

Also, I'll direct your attention to the lines #"Replaced Value24" and #"Replaced Value25", where I replaced values to change 03KET to MARKET and V2 to V-TWO. These lines exist because:

1. The earlier change of the month name from MAR to 03 impacted the word MARKETING--changed it to 03keting--so I needed to change it back; and
2. I needed to change the 2 in V2 to letters so I wouldn't have an extra digit floating around to deal with when I tried to extract the date digits.

Here's the result I get:

[image]

Beyond what I'm providing here, you might look into regex via python. I've never personally used it, but based on some light reading, it looks like it might be useful for something like this. ...at least in some fashion.

Comment: Thanks Marc.What would you recommend for values where the date is 6jul2022 for this type of dates it only extracted as 7/13/0022

Comment: Using advanced editor, change `#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if Text.Length([Custom])=5 then "0" & [Custom] else [Custom]),` in my earlier code to `#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if Number.IsOdd(Text.Length([Custom])) then "0" & [Custom] else [Custom]),`

Comment: I did try the using the above code ,but the problem still exists

Comment: When I changed `#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if Text.Length([Custom])=5 then "0" & [Custom] else [Custom]),` in my earlier code to `#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if Number.IsOdd(Text.Length([Custom])) then "0" & [Custom] else [Custom]),` it worked just fine to extract the date for a row with a value of 6jul2022 for me. If your value has more than just 6jul2022, can you provide the *complete* value so I can try it and see if it also works for me; and if it  doesn't I can try to figure out why not.